# how to find clusters with a network based on density and weight of edges in python - networkx package

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, networkx, hierarchical-clustering

I constructed a network using the python package - networkx, each edge has a weight which indicates how close the two nodes are, in terms of correlation.

It would be ideal if there is a built in algorithm that would return a clustered graph, assigning each node to it's cluster ID (1 to k).

It would be even better if it could cluster based on the weight of the edges, but not critical...

Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Are you talking about a detection of [community strucutre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure)?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into the package [python-louvain](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-louvain). With it, you can detect communities in a graph using the function `best_partition`. From the function description:

> Compute the partition of the graph nodes which maximises the
>   modularity (or try..) using the Louvain heuristices
>
> This is the partition of highest modularity, i.e. the highest partition
>   of the dendrogram generated by the Louvain algorithm.

In my example I compute the communities for the `karate_club_graph`. (Note that I use `best_partition` with the `weight` keyword even though my graph doesn't have weighted edges -- I'm just showing how would you use the function in your case.)

```
import networkx as nx
import community

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
p = community.best_partition(G, weight='weight')
print(p)
```

Output:

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 2, 9: 0, 10: 1, 11: 0, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 2, 15: 2, 16: 1, 17: 0, 18: 2, 19: 0, 20: 2, 21: 0, 22: 2, 23: 3, 24: 3, 25: 3, 26: 2, 27: 3, 28: 3, 29: 2, 30: 2, 31: 3, 32: 2, 33: 2}
```

The output is a dictionary (key = node, value = partition). The partitions go from 0 to k-1. If you need them to go from 1 to k, you can just bump the dictionary values to +1.

```
for k, v in p.items():
    p[k] = v + 1
```

Comment: An important question is whether user wants to input the value of `k` or not.

Comment: I'm getting this output:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-be9f812e7143> in <module>()
      1 G = nx.karate_club_graph()
----> 2 p = community.best_partition(G, weight='weight')
      3 print(p)

AttributeError: module 'community' has no attribute 'best_partition'

Comment: @Rob Check that you have `python-louvain` installed and that you don't have any files named `community.py` in your current directory.

Comment: @edo I found the community.py file in the following directory:

Comment: @edo I found the community.py file in the following directory:
site-packages\networkx\generators
and I've installed both community and python-louvain with pip.
Any ideas what can cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

this can help [networkx.algorithms.community.label_propagation.asyn_lpa_communities](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.label_propagation.asyn_lpa_communities.html#id3)

as per **doc**.

Returns **communities** in G as detected by asynchronous label propagation.
The **weight** of an edge is used in determining the frequency with which a label appears among the neighbors of a node.